# Readily available or commonly used transparent conductors?

Tags: wire, printed

Are they any transparent conductors (inks paints or otherwise) that are readily available to hobbyists? (i.e. cost effective and purchasable online)?

Answer (score 5):

The classic solution is [indium tin oxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indium_tin_oxide).

I have no idea about where to purchase it or if there are more modern alternatives.

Comment: [ITO coated glass](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Brand-New-Indium-Tin-Oxide-ITO-Coated-Glass-10pcs-20ohm-sq-1-x1-x1-1mm-/181107693908?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a2adc1954) is available on eBay, as is [ITO coated PET sheet](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Brand-New-Indium-Tin-Oxide-ITO-PET-1pcs-200ohm-sq-20cm-x-30cm-x-0-175mm-/181107703085?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a2adc3d2d). The glass is lower resistance, and of course of greater transparency.